# "no-unused-expressions" with TypeScript 3.7 optional call

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint, optional-chaining

I'm using TypeScript 3.7 with `@typescript-eslint/parser` and `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` for linting.

I'm trying to use optional chaining syntax and it works fine beside *optional calls*.

```js
const { hj } = window;
hj?.('formSubmitFailed'); // error
```

this gives me an error: `eslint(no-unused-expressions)`

any way to make it work with optional calls?

Comment: Did You checked eslint known issues ?? Did U use latest eslint, parser and eslint-plugin versions ???

Comment: @SkorpEN I'm using the latest versions 2.19.0, and eslint-6.8.0

Comment: There are planty of open issue in typescript-eslint releated to optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you use eslint's `no-unused-expressions` or `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions`? You have to use the latter.

Try to add this to your config:

```
rules: {
    'no-unused-expressions': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions': 2,
},
```

Comment: thanks, I will try that, could you give an explanation though?

Comment: See https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1138

Comment: that solves it, thanks! If possible explain why this change is required

Answer (score 1):

One of option is to turn off this rule that produce that error.
example how to do it(you could choose off or warn):

```
 {
   "extends": "./configs/base.json",
   "rules": {
         "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions": "off"
 }}
```

For more details see eg.:  https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1423 or how to set rules for typescript-eslint.

Comment: Of course you could also watch releases. They might make it work in version 3.0.0, but you will have to just check when new will be done.

Comment: thanks for the link to the issue, but generally I don't want to turn off the rule completely

Comment: So let it as warning. And observe issues or releases. When they will be done you could turn them on once again. In current version they not work so it should not produce error. Warning seems ok.

Comment: The rule that is being turned off in this answer actually fixes the issue.